# Why LocalBroadcastManager is not working?

Tags: android, localbroadcastmanager

I tried to learn LocalBroadcastManager. Searched in web and implemented a simple app with Two activity to perform LocalBroadcastManager. But it's not working. I can't found what's wrong with my code. please help me!

here is my code.

**FirstActivity.java**

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
            Intent intent = new Intent("localReceiver");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(FirstActivity.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    });
}    }
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hi_text);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(message, new IntentFilter("localReceiver"));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(message);
}

private BroadcastReceiver message = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("SecondActivity", "Receiver Initiated...");
        textView.setText("Intent receiver activated");
    }
};   }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".FirstActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
        android:label="SecondActivity" />

</application>
```

Comment: how can you be at the same time on `FirstActivity` and `SecondActivity` ?

Comment: @Blackbelt pls explain?

Comment: I think what @BlackBelt is saying is that is yout on `FirstActivity` but that `SecondActivity` is not running, there is no way that the receiver from second activity is registered, and so it is normal that nothing happend when you send intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are broadcasting something from `FirstActivity`, and you expect that `SecondActivity` receives it. In order this to happen you should be able to run two different `Activity`s at the same time, which is, by design, not possible. By the time you broadcast the string, you don't have anybody listening for it. Try using a `Service` to broadcast the `String`, with the receiving `Activity` resumed, and it will work

Answer (score 1):

**SecondActivity** would looks like this:

```
private BroadcastReceiver uiUpdateReceiver;
```

**onStart()**:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(SecondActivity.this).registerReceiver((uiUpdateReceiver), new IntentFilter("Your_Data");
    super.onStart();
}
```

**onCreate()**:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    uiUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
           @Override
           public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

           }
     };
}
```

**onStop()**:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ChatActivity.this).unregisterReceiver(uiUpdateReceiver);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: If you need to change views or replace fragments, you need to register it in onResume() and unregister in onPause(), otherwise it can throw an “IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState”.  This will also cut down on unnecessary system overhead.